# How do I not hoist jest.mock and use it in only one jest unit test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to mock an import and use it ONLY in 1 jest unit test, but I'm running into some issues.

This is the mock that I only want to use in 1 test

```
jest.mock("@components/components-chat-dialog", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("@components/components-chat-dialog"),
  Dialog: jest.fn().mockImplementation(({ header, content }) => (
    <div>
      <div data-testid="dialog-header">{header}</div>
      <div data-testid="dialog-content">{content}</div>
    </div>
  )),
}));
```

And here is my test suite

```
describe("My test suite here", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
   test("Renders dialog1", () => {...});
   test("Renders dialog2", () => {...});
   test("Renders dialog with mock", () => {
      // I want to only use that jest.mock(...) inside of here. 
      // I've tried to copy that mock and paste it here in my test but since jest hoists 
      // jest.mock to the top, all other tests still utilize it and break. I've also tried 
      // to create a new test suite and putting the mock in there but for some reason it 
      // still doesn't work. 
});
   test("Renders dialog3", () => {...});
})
```

I've tried something like this but it doesn't work.

```
describe("My 2nd test suite here", () => {
   jest.mock("@components/components-chat-dialog", () => ({
     ...jest.requireActual("@components/components-chat-dialog"),
     Dialog: jest.fn().mockImplementation(({ header, content }) => (
       <div>
         <div data-testid="dialog-header">{header}</div>
         <div data-testid="dialog-content">{content}</div>
       </div>
     )),
   }));
   
   test("Renders dialog with mock", () => {...});
})
```

The only way it works is when the jest.mock is placed at the top of the file outside of the test suite, and then the Renders dialog with mock test passes but all other tests fail, thus I am trying to only use this mock in the one test I need it for. Anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using [jest.spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to spy on the function/component. In any test where you want to use a mock, simply provide the spy with a mock implementation.

The `spy.mockRestore()` (or alternatively, `jest.restoreAllMocks()`) seems to be required if you want to use the real function/component in your other tests and only selectively mock it.

```
import * as dialog from '@components/components-chat-dialog'
const DialogSpy = jest.spyOn(dialog, 'Dialog')

describe('suite', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    DialogSpy.mockRestore() // Restore to the real implementation
  })

  test('use real dialog', () => { ... })

  test('use mocked dialog', () => {
    DialogSpy.mockImplementation(() => /* mock component */)
    ...
  })
})
```